# putting myself in a list

Tags: lists

I've got a sentence that starts, "As much as we – Tom, Charles, myself and a few others – saw the need for..." I set it up that way because in the context of the piece the first three of us were the most important involved and who I want to emphasize, but I wonder if that use and placement of "myself" is acceptable grammatically, vs. sticking the "few others" first and "I" at the end. Thanks,

Comment: If you want to emphasize the first three, try: *As much as we - Tom, Charles, and I (with help from a few others) - saw the need for...* There's no need for the reflexive "myself" here.

Comment: Actually, it was a group, where the first three appear earlier, so listing it the way I did was for continuity and appropriate emphasis. Rephrasing it as you suggest doesn't quite work as well. Does "Tom, Charles and I and a few others" work? I'm not sure.

Comment: If all contributions were equivalent I recommend putting yourself last, but that doesn't mean your original method is "wrong" - is there a certain style guide you want to adhere to?

Comment: No, no particular style guide. This is a letter to the editor of a small political newspaper that wouldn't change my wording, and the sentence recounts something that happened (or we were thinking) during a moment long ago. Thanks,

Comment: You can put any noun (or pronoun) in any order you wish in such a list. It's only convention (out of politeness) that *I* comes last. In what order things should appear is merely a matter of style and choice.